# Dynamically total input field values, after they have been entered, but before they are submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I don't usually use js, so am hoping for a quick win. Although I can't find the answer on SO in spite of quite a few similar questions out there.

I have a form...

```
<input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1" />
<input type="text" size="5" id="value2" name="value2" />

<input type="text" size="5" id="total" readonly="readonly" class="bckground" name="total" />
```

How can I use ajax (or otherwise) to multiply value1 by value2 after their inputs have been entered, but before the form is submitted?

Requirement is to simply display a product of value1 * value 2 as the form is being filled out. But it would be nice to embed it to the form field, as above, in case I want to add it to my database.

Edit: Below is my attempt. But I can only get a span element to update, and not automatically. Also it fails if the fields are blank.

```
<script>
function calculateSum()
{
    value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
    value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);

    sum = value1 * value2;

    document.getElementById("totalpledge").innerHTML = sum;
}
</script>
```

Seems to work with a button...

```
<input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1" />
<input type="text" size="5" id="value2" name="value2" />

<span id="totalpledge">--</span>
<span><button onclick="calculateSum()">Submit!</button></span>
```

Comment: Can you use jquery ? bind jquery.change to both and have two boolean that are set true when one is changed then if both are changed send a request to some route on your server which will return the answer and then you can do what you need with it

Comment: I think something simpler should be all I need. I made an attempt above, but had to use a button and span element, as the form input element 'total' refused to be updated.

Comment: jquery dude , it would save you a lot of hassle , with regards  it failing field are empty just check if value1/value2 have values if not make the one without equal 0 in your function

Comment: OK, show me how:) I can link Google's instance of jquery yeah?

Comment: Just curious why don't you do the calculation on the server side before saving to the database?

Comment: Because I want the user/client to be able to see the result of the calculation as they are filling the form. They are pledging donations per kilometer. The input fields are "Amount per Km Ridden" and "Distance" I will auto populate distance based on another selection, but I want total to calculate total donation amount. The site user should be able to fiddle the field to land on approximately what they want to donate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

HTML

```
<input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1" class="value"/>
<input type="text" size="5" id="value2" name="value2" class="value"/>

<input type="text" size="5" id="total" readonly="readonly" class="bckground" name="total" />
```

Just added `class="value"` to the elements so you can easily identify all of the ones that need to contribute to the total.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $total = $('#total'),
        $value = $('.value');
    $value.on('input', function(e) {
        var total = 1;
        $value.each(function(index, elem) {
            if(!Number.isNaN(parseInt(this.value, 10)))
                total = total * parseInt(this.value, 10);
        });
        $total.val(total);
    });
});
```

That binds an event handler to all of the `.value` elements (all of the elements with `class="value"`) for the `input` event, which fires whenever the value of the input changes. Then it simply iterates through each of the required inputs and multiplies their values together. Finally it puts that total value into the `#total` element.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/1/)

Comment: I love it. Thankyou:)

Comment: Oddly it doesn't work on my site. I included your jQuery in separate <script> tags in my headder, following `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` is this correct?

Comment: @square_eyes That sounds correct, yes. You also made the changes to the HTML to add `class="value"` to the `<input>` elements?

Comment: Never mind I got it to work by putting the jQuery after my </body> tag.

Comment: Is there a way to make this script scalable? I feel like using the class tag will restrict me if I need to add more to the calculation. e.g. what if I want to add or subtract a value from my total (or one of the factors before we multiply)?

Comment: Also it fails when a number in one of my factor fields is a decimal e.g. 0.5 (which I will need).

Comment: @square_eyes Ah, handling decimals is pretty easy. Change `parseInt(this.value, 10)` to `parseFloat(this.value)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

HTML part:

```
<form action="some.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1" />
    <input type="text" size="5" id="value2" name="value2" />
    <input type="text" size="5" id="total" readonly="readonly" class="bckground" name="total" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

jQuery to do the calculation:

```
$("#myForm").submit( function(e) {
    $("#total").val( parseFloat($("#value1").val()) * parseFloat($("#value2").val()) );
});
```

And then you could fetch the result by `$_POST['total']` on `some.php`.

Comment: So how do I trigger the jquery? It needs to be dynamic.

Comment: nvm, I guess I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
 value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
 value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
    if(!value1==""&&!value2=="")
    {
     sum = value1 * value2;
     document.getElementById("total").value = sum;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="some.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1"  onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
    <input type="text" size="5" id="value2" name="value2"  onkeyup="myFunction()"/>
    <input type="text" size="5" id="total" class="bckground" name="total" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This works please try this